Upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS from Jammy Jellyfish
I'm in the process of upgrading to 24.04 LTS from Jammy Jellyfish.  It has completed Setting up samba-common (2:4.19.5+dfsg-4ubuntu9) per the "terminal" display in the Distribution Upgrade window. The terminal window shows that the process has completed, but for the past 2 1/2 hours plus it has just been sitting there with the progress indicator "stuck" at about four fifths the way through.  The PC is NOT frozen--I can move the window around the screen and I get an occasional flash from the front-panel LED.  SHould I abort and re-run or waiT?

Machine: self-assembled MSI motherboard with dual boot between Ubuntu and Windows 11.  Ubuntu's "home" disk is a board-mounted one TB drive

Also: I can view ongoing processes via the top command in Linux terminal.  So the machine is not hung up; at least, I do not  believe that it is.

Check your logs for errors that might have occurred since you began the release-upgrade.
